# What does this (うつつを抜かす)ことなんてありません mean?

Tags: translation

In *Steins;Gate 0*, there is this line between a hikikomori kinda like girl and a professor who always teases her by pairing her and one of his male acquaintances together romantically.

- Girl: 恋愛なんて何の役にも立たないのに
- Professor: あら そんなことないわよ
- Professor: 何より恋愛感情も 私の大事な研究対象よ
- Girl: だからって 人を研究対象扱いしないでください 私に限ってそんなものに うつつを 抜かすことなんてありませんから

I am troubled about the last sentence here. I checked two anime streaming sites, both had the following as translation: "I will never allow myself to be fooled by the delusion of love"
How does this translation come together exactly?
My interpretation would be "There is no need to get so hooked on that thing explicitly with me" I cannot translate it properly, but basically, in my interpretation she said that there is no need (なんてことありませんから) to get so hooked on that thing (そんなものにうつつを抜かす) exclusively with me (私に限って). A more natural translation would be "Don't force that thing exclusively on me" or something like that.
Is my interpretation correct, or am I missing something and the translation is actually correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation you saw on the streaming sites is the correct one.

Although ～ことはない can mean "there is no need to ～", it also means "～ never happens" or "～ is impossible". For example, depending on the context, 彼が行くことはない means either "He doesn't have to go" or "There is no possibility that he will go". In this situation, "no possibility" is the correct interpretation because うつつを抜かす is a phrase with a fairly bad meaning, and no one suggested she *needed* to forget herself and immerse herself in love. Saying "I don't *need to* get hooked" in this context simply doesn't make much sense.

[`～に限って(～ない)` is a set phrase](https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/20100829.html), and this 私に限って is more like "(putting others aside,) as far as I am concerned" or "(I don't know about others but) at least regarding myself" or "I am the last person to ...". Of course she isn't saying she is literally the only person in the world who isn't interested in love.

> 彼に限って失敗はしない。
> He is the last person to fail. / He will never, ever fail.
> <sub>(But not "He is the only person who won't fail.")</sub>

So the original sentence translates to something along the lines of "I am the last person who gets hooked on that kind of things", "As far as I am concerned, I'll never be infatuated with such things".